# How to get the values of the highest level using .each in jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I have three levels of `div` and I am trying to get the values of the 2nd level only. I use the index parameter passed within each function to keep track. Here is my code:

```
<div id="top">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>
      <h2>
          <div>XXXXXXXXX</div>
      </h2>
  </div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

and for the script:

```
$("#top>div").each(function(index){
    $("#result").append("<p>index:" + index + " > " + $(this).text() + "</p>");
});
```

In my code I want to the result to skip xxxx and keep the index value without change.
http://jsfiddle.net/kalmarsh80/g4JSN/

Comment: It's not clear so your result should be: `index:1 > 1    index:3 > 3` ?? Can you describe the desired result?

Comment: are you looking to get just the direct div children of .top?

Comment: what's the skipping element criteria? It's literal "XXXXXXXXX" content? Being a parent? Please clarify.

Comment: What means (in your title) *`how to get values of the highest level`* ?

Comment: You want to check if `index+1` (being 0 based) equals the text?

Comment: As I said I wish to not see xxx in my example http://jsfiddle.net/kalmarsh80/g4JSN/

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like following ([**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/57Qu8/1/)):

```
$("#top > div").each(function(index){
    var txt = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    $("#result").append("<p>index:" + index + " > " + txt + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: This is good but I have the body of each div full of elements and images. Clone will duplicate that

Comment: Yes only one element will be cloned at the time and `GC` will take care of that, so what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

plz try the following:

```
$("#top>div").not(":nth-child(2)").each(function(index){
    $("#result").append("<p>index:" + index + " > " + $(this).text() + "</p>");
});
```

[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nisp/LTkh8/1/)

If you want *the value of the second level only* Then you dont need `.each`

```
    $("#result").append("<p>index:2 > " + $("#top>div").eq(1).text() + "</p>");
```

Comment: you lost track of index 1

Comment: I wasn't sure if he cared about the index ! It isn't clear from his question.

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/busor/2/edit)**

```
$("#top > div").text(function(i, t){ // Pass element index and text as arguments
  t = $(">",this)[0] ? "" : t;
  $("#result").append("<p>index:"+ i +" > "+ t +"</p>");
});
```

`$(">",this)[0]` is to check if your element has children
than using a *Conditional Operator (?:)* you just set your argument value as `""` *empty string* if true.

If you need to handle load of children elements I'd suggest you this one regarding performance:

```
var res = "";    

$("#top > div").text(function(idx, txt){
  res += "<p>index: "+ idx +" > "+ ($(">",this)[0]?"":txt) +"</p>";
});

$('#result').append( res ); // append only once!
```